# matplotlib 3: 3D scatter plots with tight_layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have some code which produces a 3D scatter plot using matplotlib's `scatter` in conjunction with `tight_layout`, see the simplified code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

N = 100
x = np.random.random(N)
y = np.random.random(N)
z = np.random.random(N)

ax.scatter(x, y, z)
plt.tight_layout()  # <-- Without this, everything is fine
plt.savefig('scatter.png')
```

In matplotlib 2.2.3 this makes a figure like so: [image]

Similar output is generated by older versions, at least back to 1.5.1. When using the new version 3.0.0, something goes wrong at `plt.tight_layout()` and I get the following output: [image]

Accompanying this is the warning

> .../matplotlib/tight_layout.py:177: UserWarning: The left and right margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations

One may argue that using `tight_layout` with no arguments as here does not (on  older matplotlibs) consistently lead to the expected tightened margins anyway, and so one should refrain from using `tight_layout` with 3D plots in the first place. However, by manually tweaking the arguments to `tight_layout` it is (used to be) a decent way to trim the margins even on 3D plots.

My guess is that this is a bug in matplotlib, but maybe they've made some deliberate change I havn't picked up on. Any pointers about a fix is appreciated.

Comment: It might not work, but a possible work around is setting the figure's size explicitly instead of using tight_layout, e.g., plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

Comment: Setting the `figsize`  is not equivalent to `tight_layout`. In addition, I am already setting `figsize` in my actual code because I care about the exact pixel size of the final image.

Comment: [This is the issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12239) and [this is the fix](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12241). I suppose you can apply it manually, i.e. making spines invisible before calling `tight_layout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by ImportanceOfBeingErnest, it now works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

N = 100
x = np.random.random(N)
y = np.random.random(N)
z = np.random.random(N)

ax.scatter(x, y, z)

# The fix
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig('scatter.png')
```

From the links in the comment, it seems that this will be fixed in matplotlib 3.0.x. For now, the above may be used.

Comment: I had a sort-of similar problem, but in my case it still didn't work in 3.0.1 where your fix is no longer required. Turned out that there seems to be another bug ([now reported](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12687)) in matplotlib: adding text to 3d-axes breaks tight_layout() if added before the call. Having this as a known working example was instrumental in figuring it out, so thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Right below your main body code of plotting.